# Cannot get started with Varnish and Wordpress - tutorial outdated?

Tags: varnish

### PROBLEM DESCRIPTION

I cannot follow the official tutorial [Wordpress with Varnish](https://www.varnish-software.com/wiki/content/tutorials/wordpress/wp_step_by_step.html#wp-step-by-step). I am using wordpress 5.7 (current version).

I have experience with networking and wordpress, and I have set up a functional test wordpress container with docker. I also started a varnish container, but the first problem is the default.vcl file - there is a typo in the tutorial, it uses `sub vcl_rec` instead of `sub vcl_recv`. I fixed this, and the container starts up successfully.

### MY default.vcl FILE

Following the tutorial and some other bits of info to enable https (in front of Varnish is a Traefik reverse proxy container, which terminates TLS connections), this is my complete default.vcl file which should at least enable caching for wordpress sites.

```
backend default {
  .host = "wp";
}

sub vcl_recv{
  if (req.url ~ "wp-admin|wp-login") {
    return (pass);
  }

  if(!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
  }

  // Remove has_js and Google Analytics __* cookies.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
  // Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

  set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-\d+=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-time-\d+=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  if (req.http.cookie == "") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
  }
}
```

Using this vcl, the site opens successfully, but nothing is ever cached.

### CHROME DEV TOOLS SCREENSHOT

Here is a screenshot of the network panel in Chrome devtools:

[image]

From a tutorial I expect to see a working result, but I think something is missing. From my limited knowledge I know that cookies prevent caching - maybe the new versions of wordpress add some extra cookies?

### INSPECTING THE LOGS

I used the command `varnishlog` to see what is happening, but I do not understand it enough. It looks to me like the cookies that might prevent caches are successfully being removed one by one? But why is it a cache miss then?

Getting the tutorial example to work should be possible without having to inspect any logs. Still, here they are:

```
*   << BeReq    >> 3440655
-   Begin          bereq 3440654 fetch
-   VCL_use        boot
-   Timestamp      Start: 1615741331.296846 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sl;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Ch-Ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: removed manually
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Server: traefik
-   BereqHeader    X-Real-Ip: myip
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: myip, 192.168.4.2
-   BereqHeader    host: removed-manually
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 3440655
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendOpen    31 default 192.168.4.4 80 192.168.4.5 43538 connect
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1615741331.297039 0.000193 0.000193
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1615741331.325222 0.028376 0.028182
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Date: Sun, 14 Mar 2021 17:02:11 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
-   BerespHeader   X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.15
-   BerespHeader   Link: <https://removed-manually.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 3186
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   TTL            RFC 120 10 0 1615741331 1615741331 1615741331 0 0 cacheable
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Filters         testgunzip
-   Storage        malloc s0
-   Fetch_Body     3 length stream
-   Gzip           u F - 3186 8579 80 80 25423
-   BackendClose   31 default recycle
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1615741331.325436 0.028589 0.000213
-   Length         3186
-   BereqAcct      817 0 817 296 3186 3482
-   End

*   << Request  >> 3440654
-   Begin          req 3440653 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1615741331.296724 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1615741331.296724 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       192.168.4.2 59606 http
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: removed-manually
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sl;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1969059563.1611504964; wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Ch-Ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: myip
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: removed-manually
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Server: traefik
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-Ip: myip
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: myip
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: myip, 192.168.4.2
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1969059563.1611504964; wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: ; wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: ; wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Host: removed-manually
-   ReqHeader      host: removed-manually
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 3440655 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1615741331.325474 0.028750 0.028750
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Date: Sun, 14 Mar 2021 17:02:11 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
-   RespHeader     X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.15
-   RespHeader     Link: <https://removed-manually.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 3186
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 3440654
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1615741331.325489 0.028765 0.000014
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1615741331.325551 0.028827 0.000061
-   ReqAcct        907 0 907 402 3186 3588
-   End
```

With all this info, can someone please help me diagnose what is wrong?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the VCL & the VSL I can conclude that your site is properly cached.

The VCL code is just there to extend the [built-in VCL][1].

The built-in VCL only serve objects from cache under the following circumstances:

- For `GET` or `HEAD` requests
- When no `Cookie` headers are present
- When no `Authorization` headers are present

The VCL logic that removes cookies, does just that. It is illustrated by the following VSL lines:

```
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1969059563.1611504964; wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: ; wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: ; wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
```

In this case the request is considered cacheable, and a cache look will happen.

The following lines show the cache lookup and subsequent cache miss:

```
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
```

> Don't worry, a cache miss is just a hit that hasn't happened yet.

The `fetch` line in the logs indicates that the WordPress backend is accessed.

For a fetched object to be stored in cache, the [built-in VCL][1] also has some rules:

- The TTL must be greater than zero
- There must be no mention of `no-cache`, `no-store` or `private` in the `Cache-Control` header
- There must be no `Set-Cookie` header in the response
- Cache variations on all headers (via `Vary: *`) are not allowed

The response you are returning doesn't trigger any non-cacheable behavior, so Varnish decides to store the object in cache.

The following VSL line illustrates this:

```
-   TTL            RFC 120 10 0 1615741331 1615741331 1615741331 0 0 cacheable
```

What it also exposes is that the object will only be cached for 120 seconds. This is because no `Expires` or `Cache-Control` header were set by your WordPress.

Here's the syntax for the *TTL* line:

```
%s %d %d %d %d [ %d %d %u %u ] %s
|  |  |  |  |    |  |  |  |    |
|  |  |  |  |    |  |  |  |    +- "cacheable" or "uncacheable"
|  |  |  |  |    |  |  |  +------ Max-Age from Cache-Control header
|  |  |  |  |    |  |  +--------- Expires header
|  |  |  |  |    |  +------------ Date header
|  |  |  |  |    +--------------- Age (incl Age: header value)
|  |  |  |  +-------------------- Reference time for TTL
|  |  |  +----------------------- Keep
|  |  +-------------------------- Grace
|  +----------------------------- TTL
+-------------------------------- "RFC", "VCL" or "HFP"
```

Because your WordPress didn't set the *TTL* via a caching header, the value of the `default_ttl` parameter is used, which defaults to 120 seconds.

However, your Google Chrome Developer Tools screenshot shows an HTTP response with a `Age: 4` header. This means that in this case the page was served from cache and had been stored in cache for 4 seconds.

Maybe because of the short time to live, you assume the page is not cached, but that is not true.

There are 2 ways to approach this:

- Set a `Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600` response header in your WordPress or webserver to increase the TTL
- Write some VCL to bypass the TTL.

Here's some VCL you can add to your VCL file:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.ttl = 1h;
}
```

This snippet will set the TTL to an hour, for every type of object stored in the cache.
[1]: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/6.0/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive reply! Of course you are right, my site was being cached. I was thrown off because I was expecting the HTTP status code to be something other than 200 (maybe 304), but it seems I must learn more about those.
The second problem was that during my first round of testing actually nothing was getting cached. I now know that it was the "wordpress_logged_in" cookie! I understand why it's not included in the tutorial, but maybe that's a pitfall for the intended audience. Thanks again, now I can continue my varnish journey.